# Return Rails error messages in a language other than English

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do we return an error message based on a config parameter?

For example, the error message for `400 Bad Request` is `param is missing or the value is empty: <param>`. If I send the config parameter `{lang: "French"}`, the French error message should be returned from the config file. Multiple translations could be stored in the config file:

```
400:
en:        "param is missing or the value is empty."
french:    "paramètres non trouvé"
```

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far? Have you read about [`I18n`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)? The *basic* idea is to store translations in `config/locales/en.yml`, `config/locales/fr.yml`, etc.

Comment: I walked thru I18n docs before, there is no example about the error messages, it mainly shows how to use different translations for messages but nothing specific for the returned error messages

Comment: If you intend to build a *custom* solution with different error messages for various HTTP codes, then you probably need to build this yourself, with standard `I18n` translations. If you're looking for ways to hook into existing rails translations such as the record validation errors, then see [section 4.1 of the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) for some pointers.

Comment: If you want to capture generic exceptions with formatted JSON error messages, you could consider placing some [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) methods in the `ApplicationController` - and then defining translations in the `locales`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in rails you have to use localization files present into **/app/config/locales** folder

For example if you have 2 locales for your app, english and french, you will have 2 YAML files:
**/app/config/locales/en.yml**

**/app/config/locales/fr.yml**

The localization keys will be provided by related localization file.
So for example:
**/app/config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  some_error_occurred: "Some error occurred."
```

**/app/config/locales/fr.yml**

```
fr:
  some_error_occurred: "Une erreur s'est produite."
```

So then in your controller or views you can show related message with something like this:

```
I18n.t('some_error_occurred', locale: :en)
```

If you don't explicit locale param, current locale will be used.

In your case you should handle the scenario into controller and then render the proper view that contain the related message.

Localization is powerful and to proper understand every aspect you should really read related documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Sounds great but can I replace your 'some_error_occurred' with 'unprocessable_entity' error so that it shows my custom French error message?

Comment: Of course, that was just an example. Maybe taking a look to how errors are managed by one of the most popular gem, Devise, can help you. checkout this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml
Here you have also other locales: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n
also FYI http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html